# Перебор массива, равно ли число любому элементу массива

Tags: javascript, jquery

Скрипт должен выставлять слово "год", если введенное число равно любому элементу массива var arr = [1, 21, 31, 41]; Выставляет, если указан конкретный элемент, например arr[0], но arr[i] не распознает

```
<input id="myTextBox" type="text"/>
<div><span class="value"></span><span class="year"></span></div>  

$("#myTextBox").on("change keyup", function() {
       var value = $(this).val()
       $('.value').text(value);       
       var arr = [1, 21, 31, 41]; // "год"
       for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
         if (value == arr[i]) {$('.year').text("год")}
         else {$('.year').text("лет")}
       }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Nata_Hamster/tfbh3paq/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

либо пишите на чистом JS либо используйте только JQ.

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.inarray/

```js
$("#myTextBox").on("change keyup", function () {
    var value = $(this).val()
    value = parseInt(value)
    $('.value').text(value);

    var arr = [1, 21, 31, 41]; // "год"

    if (-1 !== $.inArray(value, arr)) {
        $('.year').text("год")
    } else {
        $('.year').text("лет")
    }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>[1, 21, 31, 41]; // "год"</p>
<input id="myTextBox" type="text" />
<div><span class="value"></span> <span class="year"></span></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
     if (value == arr[i]) {
       $('.year').text("год"); 
       return;
     }
   }
   $('.year').text("лет");
```